# keep first N charatcer in a column in MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have list of Strings like this in a column in my access and would need to trim the names like below.

Strings:

```
bposdfr45rty
asdfvgfhgfrs
```

Expected Output:

```
bposdfr4
asdfvgfh
```

I need to keep just first 8 characters and delete other characters

Really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a text field in a table that you wish to truncate to 8 characters? If so, an update query seems the simplest solution.

Comment: I am very new to Access.update query works excellent! :)
Tnx alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Blackhawk is referring to looks like this:

```
Update tableName <br />
Set columnName =  Left(columnName, 8) <br />
Where somecolumn = some critera
```

in the SQL View in an Access query.  The important line is the middle one that reads Set columnName = Left(columnName, 8)

Left(columnName, 8) is a function that will truncate the values in the column named "columnName" to the first 8 characters.

Access also has [Right()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/right.php) and [Mid()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php) functions for other string truncation work.

You can ignore the Where clause if you want to truncate all the values in the table.  If you only want to truncate some of the values you can set a criteria (like somecolumn = true or someColumn > 25) and only the records that satisfy the criteria will be updated.